What value does the html datepicker send when the user does not select a date?
I'm writing some PHP to display and process an input form that includes a date picker, identified by
<input type="date" id="offdate" name="offdate">

When the user selects a date, I've placed the date in a session variable, and what I'd like to do is use the session variable if the user doesn't select another date value.
Is there a way in PHP to identify if the date picker value is empty?  I see plenty of examples in Javascript but I didn't see any PHP examples.
I've tried using the empty() and is_null() functions but can't find one that will identify an empty date picker value.
Sorry to respond back so late, but here's the code in question.
if(isset($_POST['AddOffering'])) {
    if ($_POST['offdate'] !== "01-01-1970"){
        $offdate = $_POST['offdate'];
        $_SESSION["date"]=$offdate;
    }
    elseif(empty($_POST['offdate'])) {
        $offdate = $_SESSION['offdate'];
        echo "session ".$_SESSION["date"];
    }

The remainder of the first 'if' statement is code that processes the rest of the form.  Basically I have a button called 'AddOffering' and a HTML date picker called 'offdate.'  I'd like to place the value of offdate into a session variable that can be accessed each time the form is displayed.  If the user selects a new date and changes 'offdate' then that new value would be in the session variable.
Thanks!

If the datepicker is empty then you should get an empty value in PHP. How are you sending the datepicker's value to PHP exactly? Is it just a regular form submission? Or is there more to it? It's hard to see why something like if (empty($_POST["offdate"])) wouldn't have worked for you. To get better help please provide a [mre] of your issue including all relevant code needed to recreate the scenario, rather than just tiny snippets and vague descriptions. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post. I'm sure we will be able to explain the issue if you show us precisely what you did.

P.S. This is no different than any other form field in a HTML form... a date field is not a special case in that respect.

Based on the information you provided, if you want to check the session value when the page is being built by php before sending it to the client the empty() or is_null() methods will suffice.
Now, if you want to check the session variable after the page is rendered into the client you should make a ajax request to some endpoint to check it and return a boolean or something.
If you want to check if the html field has a value after being rendered into the client you should use javascript.
